# Why do we use "in" in the phrase "in front of"?

Tags: grammar, etymology, idioms, prepositions, word-usage

I just realized I can't quite make out why we use the word "in." The meaning of front is generally a surface, a side - not a space you can be "in," so how did that happen? Is it an artifact of an older meaning of "front"? Was "front" also once the name of the space in front of something?

After all, "in the front" does refer to a space (I exclude "at" because "at" by nature converts an object to a location), yet particularly refers to an interior (real or abstract) space. But all you do is drop "the" and now it's an external reference. Curious.

It's so hard to Google this or search it on here because so many questions use the phrase in asking about word choices, order, etc.

Comment: Mainly because it's a well-established idiom.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about the past; history / origin. *Today* it doesn't seem to make logical sense - maybe it once did?

Answer (score 1):

If an object is “in front of” something, it is *in* the space that is in front of the object. I have provided a simple diagram below to model this idea:[image]

## Edit

Perhaps this quote from Wiktionary will help:

> At or near the front part of (something). 
>   In the presence of, in view of (someone).
>   Not in front of the children!
>   Located before, ahead of, previous to (someone or something). 
>   I'll take the one in front of the black one.

Comment: So why don't we say "**in** [the space] **behind of**"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because _behind_ is not used as a noun except in the sense of "buttocks". I think you should have asked about "back", which is the noun opposite of "front". In fact, "in back of" is the exact opposite of "in front of" in American English. In BE, though, it has to be "at the back of" instead. So a more pertinent question would be "why don't we Brits say _in back of_?"

Comment: I'm not asking the meaning.

"The meaning of front is generally a surface, a side - not a space you can be "in,"

"how did that happen? Is it an artifact of an older meaning of "front"? Was "front" also once the name of the space in front of something?"

Comment: @listeneva *at the front* would be the opposite of *at the back*. "We were seated at the front" and "We were seated at the back". The meaning of *behind* is opposite to the meaning of *in front of*, e.g "behind the building" (outside) and "in front of the building" (outside), so that is why I mentioned "behind". I think *in front of* is just an idiom or fixed phrase, and there is no real or foolproof reason why  "in" instead of "at" is used. If there ever was an explanation, it's forgotten now.

Comment: Although come to think of it, we do say *in the middle* of something.

Comment: What do you mean "The meaning of front is generally a surface, a side - not a space you can be "in"?  If you were in a theatre (or similar) you could say "I was sitting in front of Fred (who was in the row behing me)". Surely, you're then sitting ***in** a space in front of Fred*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Discussing _at the back_ or _at the front_ is neither here nor there, when the OP specifically asks about _in front of_. Since _front_ is a noun in _in front of_, I don't understand how discussing the preposition _behind_ is any helpful. Like I said, the question should be why _in back of_ is possible only in AmE and not in BrE when _in front of_ is possible in both sides of the pond.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's no problem! Maybe continue your conversation in chat, though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, "middle" IS a space though, so that's fine.  Front is the weird one. Its history can't be forgotten! Where is the answer!? Lol. I've never heard "in back of" used seriously in the US.  if someone does, i feel in general it would just be seen as wrong. But i found another stack exchange questions that revealed "in back of" is claimed acceptable and established in some dictionaries. So actually there's two examples where "in" doesn't seem to make sense. Back is also either an interior space or surface - today at least. I'll try googling both together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically considering this an invalid question because the premise was invalid for this particular question as asked. Although no one pointed it out, my claim on the nature of the phrase from a current perspective was seeing "front" as a noun, but that would require something like "a" or "the" - this version does exist and does mean a space as expected. Although the possibility of a noun-based origin remains, there's no difference between this and other words and phrases such as "on top" or even "beside."

I was seeing "in front of" as a unique case but it's not. This question would have to change to be about the etymology of various prepositional words and phrases in general.